JasperReports Column Header Split Across and Duplicated at Page Break
I'm working with JasperReports Studio 6.21.1 and encountering an issue where the column header is being duplicated and split across pages when a page break occurs. This is not how I want it, as I want the column header to be printed with the detail band on the next page when there is not enough space for both the bands to be printed.
Here's a snippet of my JRXML code, focusing on the column header and detail band sections:
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Prevent">
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="5" width="555" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3df22ab3-ca84-43ec-9fbf-0e15d1963657"/>
            <!-- Column header content -->
        </frame>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="60" splitType="Prevent">
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="e52f32dd-f377-4cbe-9aec-961f112d1ad9">
                <!-- Detail band content -->
            </reportElement>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>

My Column header duplicated and split from detail
I've set the splitType attribute of both the column header and detail bands to Prevent, but the column header still gets split at the end of the page.
How to ensure the column header is printed with the detail band on the next page, preventing it from being split or duplicated?
